# MySQL - Getting "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction"

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I have created one table with 4 columns in Oracle `MySQL` DB and the version 5.7. The total records present in DB is 4 912 442. Now i am trying to insert one more 100 000 records into the `MySQL` DB.

I have created simple `Spring Boot` application and reading the records from file and inserting to the `MySQL` DB.

Getting the below error while inserting records into `MySQL` DB after the records count 4912442 :

```
[WARN ] SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1205, SQLState: 40001
[ERROR] SqlExceptionHelper - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

Note: The MySQL DB is using in 2 instance by MASTER-MASTER Cluster.

and also executed below commands even getting the above error :

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 5000; 
SET innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 5000;
```

Comment: Extend the timeout or load the data in batches and commit after each batch.

Comment: Executed these commands `SET GLOBAL innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 5000; 
SET innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 5000;` even getting the above error and also used commit in mysql command line prompt and tried again to inserting and getting the same error. Please hlep me on this. @Gordon Linoff

Comment: Lock timeout might mean that you have a deadlock somewhere. Increasing the timeout would probably not help if that is the case but it all depends on what the transaction is actually doing

Comment: how i can check that "deadlock" can you please help me to check and resolve this. Thanks. @apokryfos

Answer (score 0):

`Lock wait timeout` generally occurs when a transaction update/insert is waiting on row(s) of data which is already been locked by some other transaction.

The possible causes may be a  large amount of data, inappropriate table design,,constraints etc.

here are some solutions should work:

1. Check current value of lock wait time `show variables like 'innodb_lock_wait_timeout`; and update it to `120` something a higher value.
2. OR You can set it to higher value in /etc/my.cnf permanently with this line but make sure you restart MySQL, if you can not restart then just run query `SET GLOBAL innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 120;`

   ```
   [mysqld]
   innodb_lock_wait_timeout=120
   ```